# Should battery be disconnected on both terminals?

Tags: high-voltage, automotive, contactor

I am building an EV and I was wondering, should I disconnect only positive or both main HV battery terminals? Which option do car manufacturers use? I don't see any disadvantages with disconnecting only one, unless there is some damage to battery pack and possible short circuit to car's body.

Here's approximate schematic:

[image]

Should I use only A1, A2 relays or also B's?

Comment: Have you considerer safety issues, or when one of the switches fails? Also include a **schematic** to show what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For safety reasons, it's a must to disconnect both ends of the battery. Because it's a high-voltage source and should be treated as such - just like making the phase and neutral conductors dead before working with live voltages. And that's what manufacturers do.

There are different options like using contactors on both sides, or using semiconductor switches at positive-side and contactors at negative side.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THAT!

Never connect batteries in parallel through individual switches, especially Li-ion batteries.

If you do, while one switch is off, the other battery is in use, and its State of Charger (SoC) changes. when the switch is turned back on, a large amount of power flows from the most charged battery to the least charged battery. The high inrush current at best degrades the batteries, and at worst causes damage.

If you *must* place batteries in parallel, 1) measure their voltages to ensure they are at the same voltage, and 2) connect them *permanently* in parallel.

Do use switches, yes, but wire them so that they interrupt the *total* current from all the batteries permanently in parallel. Do not use individual switches for each battery.

To answer your question: yes, for safety on a battery 48 V and higher, use two switches, one on each end of the battery. Use actual mechanical switches (relays, contactors) not solid state ones (MOSFETs, Solid State Relays). That provides "galvanic isolation".

Comment: I understand the problem, thus I would measure voltage before closing contactors for parallel connection.

Comment: _I understand the problem_, I don't think you do. You only measure once, and that time will be fine. But the next time you won't measure, and that's when damage will occur. That's why the parallel connection must be PERMANENT. So that there can't be a second time.

Comment: Why I wouldnt I measure it second time? I would measure it every time before closing contactors.

Comment: Because that switch will be opened and closed 100 times during the lifetime of the battery. The first time, you're there, and you can check the voltages. The second time to the 100th time, you're not there, you don't check the voltages. The second time in particular, that's when bad things happen, to the point that there might not be a 3rd time.